# How to resolve memory issues in iOS swift while fetching data from sqlite database in collection view

Tags: swift, sqlite, memory-management, memory-leaks, uicollectionviewcell

I am using sqlite database which is having more than 1000 records and fetching data inside collection view cell. I have use custom collection cell to display data. When I perform action on button and reload collection view most time I got memory issues.So I am sharing my code Kindly guide me as I am new in swift.

in my viewDidLoad , I fill my array list from database

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Register cell
    navigationView.dropShadow()
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "HomeViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "HomeViewCell")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


    profilesArray.removeAll()
    profileImageArray.removeAll()


    let tempProfilesArray = masterDBObj.retriveMsterData(fromDB: "PROFILE", withGroupName: groupname)


    //Get offers IMG data from local DB / Remove duplicates - sub sets
    let IMGDBObj = TCMasterImageDB()

    var sameProfileSet: Set<AnyHashable> = []
    for i in 0 ..< tempProfilesArray!.count {//tempProfilesArray!.count
        autoreleasepool {
            guard let DBObj = tempProfilesArray![i] as? TCMasterDB else {return}

            guard let IMGArray = IMGDBObj.retriveIMGData(fromDB: "PROFILE", withCode: DBObj.codeString) else {return}
            let destinationName = DBObj.nameString
            if !sameProfileSet.contains(destinationName){
                print("Profile name : \(DBObj.nameString)")
                if !(DBObj.nameString == "25-OH VITAMIN D (TOTAL)" ||  DBObj.nameString == "HbA1c"){

                    profilesArray.append(DBObj)
                    profileImageArray.append(IMGArray)
                    sameProfileSet.insert(destinationName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function is used to display data in cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    self.customCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeViewCell", for: indexPath) as? HomeViewCell

    self.customCell!.configureCell(imageName: self.profilesArray[indexPath.item].nameString, cell: self.customCell!, forItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)

    self.customCell!.lblTes.text! = self.profilesArray[indexPath.row].nameString

    var subIMGArray = self.profileImageArray[indexPath.row] as! Array<Any>
    if subIMGArray.count == 0 {
        self.customCell!.profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "OfferProfileDefault.png")
    }else{
        var IMGDBObj = TCMasterImageDB()
        IMGDBObj = subIMGArray[0] as! TCMasterImageDB
        self.customCell!.profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        self.customCell!.profileImageView.image = ImageManager.imageNamed("OfferProfileDefault.png")
        self.customCell!.profileImageView.loadImage(fromURL: IMGDBObj.imgLocationString!)
    }

    let offerDBObj = self.profilesArray[indexPath.row]
    self.customCell!.testRateLbl.text = "\(offerDBObj.testCountString!) tests @ ₹ \(offerDBObj.rateB2CString!)"

    self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.tag = (indexPath.row)
    self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myProfileCartAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    //Offer price

    if TCUtilityManager.retrieve(fromUserDefaults: "USERTYPE") == "LOYALTY"{
        //LOYALTY_DISCOUNT
        let loyaltyDiscout: Float = Float(TCUtilityManager.retrieve(fromUserDefaults: "LDISCOUNT")) ?? 0.0
        let offerRateAmount: Float = Float(offerDBObj.ratePayAmountString)!
        let finalAmount = Int(roundf(offerRateAmount * (loyaltyDiscout / 5)) * 5)

        if finalAmount == 0 {
            if (offerDBObj.rateB2CString == offerDBObj.ratePayAmountString) {
                self.customCell!.testRateLbl.text = "\(offerDBObj.testCountString!) tests @ ₹ \(offerDBObj.rateB2CString!)"
            } else {
                self.customCell!.testRateLbl.text = "\(offerDBObj.testCountString!) tests @ ₹ \(offerDBObj.rateB2CString!)"
            }
        }else{
            if Int(offerDBObj.rateB2CString) == finalAmount {
                self.customCell!.testRateLbl.text = "\(offerDBObj.testCountString!) tests @ ₹ \(finalAmount)"
            } else {
                self.customCell!.testRateLbl.text = "\(offerDBObj.testCountString!) tests @ ₹ \(finalAmount)"
            }

        }

    }else{
        if (offerDBObj.rateB2CString == offerDBObj.ratePayAmountString) {
            self.customCell!.testRateLbl.text = "\(offerDBObj.testCountString!) tests @ ₹ \(offerDBObj.ratePayAmountString!)"
        } else {
            self.customCell!.testRateLbl.text = "\(offerDBObj.testCountString!) tests @ ₹ \(offerDBObj.ratePayAmountString!)"
        }
    }

    //Cart button


    let addToCartValue = offerDBObj.addTestToCartString!
    print("Result : \(addToCartValue)")
    //        autoreleasepool {
    //            DispatchQueue.main.async {
    switch addToCartValue {
    case "TRUE","TRUE_WITHOUT_PROFILE":
        self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        //            customCell!.addToCartBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "cart_Nav"), for: .normal)//red
        self.customCell!.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8922533393, green: 0.2110714018, blue: 0.2173824012, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.topView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8922533393, green: 0.2110714018, blue: 0.2173824012, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.lblTes.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.customCell!.testRateLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8922533393, green: 0.2110714018, blue: 0.2173824012, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.setTitle("REMOVE", for: .normal)

        break

    case "TRUE_WITH_PROFILE","TRUE_WITH_OFFER","TRUE_WITH_THYRONOMICS":
        self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.customCell!.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.topView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.lblTes.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.testRateLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.501960814, green: 0.501960814, blue: 0.501960814, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.setTitle("INCLUDE", for: .normal)

        break
    default:
        self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.customCell!.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.topView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.lblTes.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.testRateLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8922533393, green: 0.2110714018, blue: 0.2173824012, alpha: 1)
        self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        self.customCell!.addToCartBtn.setTitle("ADD", for: .normal)

        break
    }
    //            }
    //        }

    print("end Result : \(addToCartValue)")

    return customCell! // return your cell
}
```

Comment: From a quick glance at your code, you're loading the entire database into memory, which defeats the point of sqlLite. Instead, revise your code to figure out just those records you need for what's actually onscreen, and load just those. When your list is scrolled you'll have to drop some records and load others - the idea is to just maintain the ones you need. Or, try writing code where an sql call for the individual record populates data inside the call to build the individual cell, eliminating having to maintain the on-screen record buffer, relying on sqlLite to do the caching.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment .I will definitely try what do you have suggested.